# How can I relate data in a pivot table to a normal table in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, many-to-many

I'm working on a new Laravel project and I'm facing a kind of relationship that I never encountered before. Basically, I have these models

```
Activity
 - activity_id
 - activity_name
 - activity_description
 - category_id (foreign on categories)
```

```
Phase
 - phase_id
 - phase_name
 - phase_description
```

```
Risk 
 - risk_id
 - risk_name
 - risk_description
```

Phase and Activity are ManyToMany related. Then I have a pivot Table between Phase and Activity defined in a model

```
PhaseActivity
 - id
 - phase_id
 - activity_id
```

Also, Phase and Risk are ManyToMany related. Then I would have had a pivot between Phase and Risk

```
PhaseRisk
 - id
 - phase_id
 - risk_id
```

Then I have some other Models that have to be related to this specific Phase/Risk relationship. I.E. one of these model:

```
PPM

 - ppm_id
 - ppm_name
 - ppm_description
```

I would like to create a relationship between the pivot table PhaseRisk and this model (PPM). But I didn't find any solution till now. How can I create this kind of nested relationships?

I expect to create a relationship that can be displayed in a sort of treeview like this:

```
Activity-1
 - Phase-1
   - Risks
     - Risk-1
       - PPMS
     - Risk-2
       - PPMS
   - Tools
     - Tool-1
       - Risk-1
       - Risk-2
```

Comment: Sorry I posted the question by mistake before editing it correctly. Thank you for editing correctly.